# Newly added network card disabled

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek

**Background:**
I want to link CCTV server directly to my Ubuntu PC to record the streams from the CCTV onto the Ubuntu PC.

I want to keep the network traffic from the CCTV server isolated from the rest of my network, so I decided to add another network card to the PC to allow me to have a peer to peer link with the CCTV server.

**Problem:**
I installed a new generic network card in the PC which uses a Realtek 8100/8101L/8139 chipset.

When I rebooted after installing the card, it did not appear to work.

```
ifconfig
```

Returns

```
enp0s14: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.0.102  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
    inet6 fe80::250:8dff:fed3:63a0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:50:8d:d3:63:a0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 20937  bytes 12660083 (12.6 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 22521  bytes 4156566 (4.1 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 22  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 10794  bytes 547578 (547.5 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 10794  bytes 547578 (547.5 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

enp0s14 is the built in network adapter on my motherboard which is still working fine and connects me to my home network.

There's no entry listed relating to the newly installed NIC.

```
lspci | grep Ethernet
```

Returns

```
00:0b.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter (rev 10)
00:0e.0 Ethernet controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6120/VT6121/VT6122 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter (rev 11)
```

So it seems that the new card is detected, but not enabled.

```
dmsg | grep Network
```

Returns

```
[    1.575821] FUJITSU Extended Socket Network Device Driver - version 1.2 - Copyright (c) 2015 FUJITSU LIMITED
[    1.611683] VIA Networking Velocity Family Gigabit Ethernet Adapter Driver Ver. 1.15
[    1.611686] Copyright (c) 2002, 2003 VIA Networking Technologies, Inc.
[    1.618755] eth0: VIA Networking Velocity Family Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
[   16.301456] audit: type=1400 audit(1506850485.331:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=646 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.301457] audit: type=1400 audit(1506850485.331:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=646 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

This only seems to mention the VIA chipset drivers and not the Realtek ones.

So does this mean that the drivers are not installed?

Googling the Realtek site says that the Linux 8100 series drivers are not available for download because they are incorporated in the Linux kernel, so am I right in thinking that I don't need to install any and it should just work?

Any ideas on how to enable this adapter would be much appreciated.

Thanks

** Solution **

This appeared to be down to drivers in the end.

rtl8139 driver module is supposedly included in the kernel, but it seems that for my installation it wasn't, so when I tried "lsmod | grep rtl" nothing was found.

modprobe rtl8139 did not work, but when I tried modprobe 8139too, this worked after a full reboot.

Thanks to vidarlo for the assistance with this resolution.

Comment: please give the output of `rfkill list`

Comment: Isn't rfkill for wifi? I don't have any wifi adapters installed these are both wired connections.

Comment: rfkill is for wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll explain why you see this behaviour first. If you just want the solution, skip to the bottom :)

Network cards that is administratively down (e.g. ifconfig nic down) will not show up in the list by default. A short example from one of my boxen:

```
[~]$ ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 84:1b:5e:27:38:80  
          inet addr:10.0.1.64  Bcast:10.0.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: <redacted>/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: <redacted>/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: <redacted>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8278086 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:7 frame:7
          TX packets:1286330 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:11747172316 (10.9 GiB)  TX bytes:150285863 (143.3 MiB)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:364 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:364 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:24920 (24.3 KiB)  TX bytes:24920 (24.3 KiB)

[~]$
```

The box has two NIC's, eth0 and eth1 (It's running an older Debian release, so interface names are the traditional ethX, but this doesn't matter here).

`ip link` on the other hand shows all interfaces:

```
[~]$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:1b:5e:27:38:80 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:1b:5e:27:38:81 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

If it does not show up using `ip link`, please run `lsmod | grep rtl`. `rtl8139` should be loaded. If, for some strange reason, it isn't please try `sudo modprobe rtl8139 && ip link` to manually load the module and list interfaces again.

If you're using Network Manager, it can be configured using `sudo nmtui`, and selecting 'Activate a connection'. If you don't use Network Manager, you can edit `/etc/network/interfaces` as root, and add the NIC. The format is fairly simple:

```
auto <interfacename>
 iface <interfacename> inet static
 address   <ip address>
 broadcast <broadcast>
 netmask   <netmask>
```

Replace  with what `ip link` shows. Replace the various address parameters with what's applicable for your CCTV network.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I tried nmtui and selected Activate for Wired Connection 2, but it returns an error saying "Connection 'Wired connection 2' is not available on the device enp0s11 at this time"

Comment: Also tried editing /etc/network/interfaces, but when I try to restart the network service afterwards it says "failed". Checking jounalctl -xe returns: Oct 01 20:29:56 GS720 NetworkManager[728]: <info>  [1506886196.2511] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="1b9230c2-8a53-4cc0-86fa-db47a36d9b94" name="Wired connection 2" pid=5535 uid=0 result="fail" reason="Connection 'Wired connection 2' is not available on the device enp0s11 at this time."

Comment: Did you configure it with static IP, or with DHCP? If DHCP, is there a DHCP available at the network in question?

Comment: I tried both, although it should probably be static. The CCTV server is one of those PVRs running embedded Linux, so my plan was to enter a static IP on that and on my PC and hopefully that should be it. When I entered IPs in /etc/network/interfaces, I left out the broadcast parameter. Is that needed and if so what should I put in it?

Comment: Broadcast is generally the last address in the network. If the netmask is 255.255.255.0, and the IP 192.168.1.10, the broadcast would be 192.168.1.255

But your settings may be managed by Network Manager? Try adding the connection with nmtui :)

Comment: Tried setting the static IP with nmtui, then selected Activate, but got: "Could not activate connection: Activation Failed." I would have thought that regardless of what I'm connecting it to, with no network cable plugged in I should still be able to activate the connection shouldn't I, in which case even selecting DHCP should work to get it up and running, then I can change it to a static IP afterwards when I plug the cable in, but neither seems to work. I think it must be either the drivers or a hardware conflict that is preventing it from enabling.

Comment: Connect a cable, and try then. NM generally wants link before activating.

Comment: Tried connecting it to my main network which has working DHCP, but no joy. It then goes back the error "Connection 'Wired connection 2' is not available on the device enp0s11 at this time". Also tried a static IP on that network, but again says "Cannot activate connection". I will have to leave it for tonight and pick this up again tomorrow. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Finally working. I did some more checking on the relevant driver module and discovered that instead of rtl8139, I could use the 8139too module. After enabling this with modprobe I did a network restart, but that didn't seem to work, so I did a full restart and this time when the system came back up, the network card was working. ifconfig shows both wired network connections as active. Thanks vidarlo for your assistance.

Comment: Excellent that you found the problem :)